# Kivy: Using tools for imaging

Tags: python, kivy

I am testing code which draws aset of images and ellipse. The code is very simple, but I don't understand the result of it:

- Why is the ellipse white
- How did it make a white square?

Can you explain this to me?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle, Ellipse
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivy.uix.image import Image

class Scene(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Scene, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1,1,0)

            wimg = Image(source = 'grase.png', pos = (50, 50))
            wimg = Image(source = 'grase.png', pos = (90, 50))
            wimg = Image(source = 'grase.png', pos = (130,50))
            wimg = Image(source = 'grase.png', pos = (170,50))
            wimg = Image(source = 'grase.png', pos = (210,50))

            wimg = Ellipse(size=(20,20), pos = (250,180))

        return

class DogApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.g = Scene()
        return self.g

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DogApp().run()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Image is a widget, not a graphic instruction.
Try like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle, Ellipse
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image


class Scene(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Scene, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1,1,0)
            Ellipse(size=(20,20), pos = (250,180))

        for i in range(0,450,50):
            self.add_widget(Image(source = 'grase.png', pos = (i,50)))


class DogApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.g = Scene()
        return self.g


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DogApp().run()
```